# Actualizar registros usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un formulario donde donde rescato un registro de una base de datos y un botón de actualizar para editar el registro en cuestión.

La parte del formulario donde muestro los datos de un registro cualquiera funciona bien, la página muestra todos los campos correctamente. Es cuando pulso en el botón actualizar que no consigo editar correctamente los campos, lo que hace es vaciar el registro completamente.

Llevo un buen rato probando y probando pero no consigo ver donde está el error. Os muestro lo que tengo.

**Fichero donde recojo los datos del formulario en includes/datoscliente.php**

Lo que pretendo con esto es no tener que estar escribiendo constantemente las variables de los campos de los formularios.

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST["idcliente"];
    $datonombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $datoapellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
    $datoalias = $_POST["alias"];
    $datotelefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $datomovil = $_POST["movil"];
    $datoemail = $_POST["email"];
    $datodireccion = $_POST["direccion"];
    $datopoblacion = $_POST["poblacion"];
    $datoprovincia = $_POST["provincia"];
    $datocodigopostal = $_POST["codigopostal"];
    $tratamientocapilar = $_POST["tratamientocapilar"];
    $tratamientocorporal = $_POST["tratamientocorporal"];
    $observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"];
?>
```

**El formulario donde rescato los datos de un cliente en función de la ID (editar.php)**

Esta parte funciona bien y no da problemas. Uso una clase que se llama `EditarCliente` que contiene una sentencia mysql que busca el cliente por la ID.

```
<?php
   // Incluimos la clase EditarCliente
   require("includes/editarcliente.php");

   // Instanciamos un objeto de la clase editar clientes
   $cliente = new EditarCliente;

   // Traemos el valor del cliente a editar
   $idcliente = $_GET['id'];

   // Creamos un objeto nuevo que traiga el cliente a editar usando el método EditClient de EditarCliente
   $editarcliente = $cliente->EditClient($idcliente);

   // Recorremos todo el array y guardamos cada elmento del campo en su correspondiente variable
   foreach ($editarcliente as $elemento) {
      $id = $elemento['idclientes'];
      $nombre = $elemento['nombre'];
      $apellidos = $elemento['apellidos'];
      $alias = $elemento['alias'];
      $telefono = $elemento['telefono'];
      $movil = $elemento['movil'];
      $email = $elemento['email'];
      $direccion = $elemento['direccion'];
      $poblacion = $elemento['poblacion'];
      $provincia = $elemento['provincia'];
      $codigopostal = $elemento['codigopostal'];
      $tratamientocapilar = $elemento['tratamientocapilar'];
      $tratamientocorporal = $elemento['tratamientocorporal'];
      $observaciones = $elemento['observaciones'];
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html lang="es">
    <head>
     <?php
     // Incluimos el header de la página
      include("includes/header.php");
     ?>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div class="container">
             <header class="header">
                  <h1>Gestión Clientes <small>NNNN</small></h1>
             </header>
         </div>
         <div class="container menu-create">
           <form action="actualizarcliente.php" method="POST">
              <div class="form-horizontal">
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">ID Cliente</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="idcliente" id="idcliente" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $id;?>" required>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $apellidos;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Alias</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $alias;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Teléfono</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $telefono;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Móvil</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="number" name="movil" id="movil" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $movil;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $email;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Dirección</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $direccion;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Población</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="poblacion" id="poblacion" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $poblacion;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Provincia</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $provincia;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Código Postal</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="number" name="codigopostal" id="codigopostal" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $codigopostal;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tratamiento Capilar</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="tratamientocapilar" id="tratamientocapilar" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $tratamientocapilar;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tratamiento Corporal</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="tratamientocorporal" id="tratamientocorporal" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $tratamientocorporal;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Observaciones</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="text" name="observaciones" id="observaciones" class="form-control input_size" value="<?php echo $observaciones;?>" required>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                           <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default">Salvar</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
            </form>
         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Clase ModificarCliente (modificarcliente.php)**

Tengo esta clase para modificar al cliente con este código:

```
<?php

   // Incluimos los datos del formulario para PHP
   require("datosclientes.php");

    // Incluimos la clase conexión para crear una que herede de Conexion
    require("conexion.php");

    /*
    * Clase modificar cliente que hereda las propiedades de la clase conexion
    */
   class ModificarCliente extends Conexion {

       // Constructor de la clase
       function __construct(){

           // Constructor de la super clase
           parent::__construct();

       }

    // Método para guardar las modificaciones del cliente
    public function ModificarCliente($id) {

       // try and catch para capturar errores
       try {

           // Sentencia SQL
           $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET
                    nombre = '$datonombre',
                    apellidos = '$datoapellidos',
                    alias = '$datoalias',
                    telefono = '$datotelefono',
                    movil = '$datomovil',
                    email = '$datoemail',
                    direccion = '$datodireccion',
                    poblacion = '$datopoblacion',
                    provincia = '$datoprovincia',
                    codigopostal = '$datocodigopostal',
                    tratamientocapilar = '$tratamientocapilar',
                    tratamientocorporal = '$tratamientocorporal',
                    observaciones = '$observaciones'
                WHERE idclientes = '$id'";

            // Guardamos la variable SQL y preparamos la consulta con la conexion de la base de datos
            $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

            // Ejecutamos la consulta y la guardamos en un array
            $query->execute(array());

            // Guardamos el resultado en una variable
            $resultado = $query;

            // Cerramos la query
            $query->closeCursor();

            // Devolvemos los resultados a la función
            return $resultado;

            // Vaciamos el objeto
            $this->conexion_db = null;

         } catch (Exception $e) {

           echo "Error en la ejecución de la consulta<br>";
           echo "Mensaje: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>";
           echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine();

       }

    }
}
?>
```

Y por último tengo la página **actualizarcliente.php** donde instancio la clase `ModificarCliente` usando el método `ModificarCliente` con el parámetro `$id` que tengo del formulario editar.php

```
<?php

   // Incluimos los datos del formulario para PHP
   require("includes/datosclientes.php");

   // Incluimos la clase Modificar cliente
   require("includes/modificarcliente.php");

   // Instanciamos un objeto de modificar cliente
   $modificarcliente = new ModificarCliente;

   $modificarcliente->ModificarCliente($id);

   echo $id;

   if($modificarcliente == false) {
      echo "error";
   } else {
      echo "Cliente modificado";
   }
?>
```

**El problema**

Cuando pulso en el botón Salvar del formulario editar.php lo que hace el programa es vaciarme el registro en cuestión. Es decir, si estoy editando al cliente con id 12 me vacía todos los campos del cliente con id 12.

Cuando lo ejecute me muestra un error por cada campo del formulario:

> Notice: Undefined variable: datonombre in C:\wamp64\www\elena\includes\modificarcliente.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: datoapellidos in C:\wamp64\www\elena\includes\modificarcliente.php on line 32

Y luego en los errores que muestro con la clase `ModificarCliente` indica lo siguiente:

> Mensaje: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Sin embargo el if lo hace y muestra el texto "Cliente Modificado".

Tengo con un include los datos de los formularios, pero por los errores que marca es como si PHP no consiga rescatar los datos del formulario `editar.php`.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

**var_dump($sql)**

```
C:\wamp64\www\nnn\includes\modificarcliente.php:48:string 'UPDATE clientes SET

                    nombre = 'David',

                    apellidos = 'nnn',

                    alias = 'nnn',

                    telefono = '000000000',

                    movil = '00000',

                    email = 'a@a.com',

                    direccion = 'nnnn',

                    poblacion = 'nnnn',

                    provincia = 'p',

                    codigopostal = '222',

                    tratamientocapilar = 'prueba',

     '... (length=645)
```

**var_dump($datos)**

```
array (size=15)
  'idcliente' => string '11' (length=2)
  'nombre' => string 'David' (length=5)
  'apellidos' => string 'nnn' (length=15)
  'alias' => string 'nnn' (length=6)
  'telefono' => string '000000000' (length=9)
  'movil' => string '00000' (length=5)
  'email' => string 'a@a.com' (length=7)
  'direccion' => string 'nnn' (length=14)
  'poblacion' => string nnn' (length=12)
  'provincia' => string 'p' (length=1)
  'codigopostal' => string '222' (length=3)
  'tratamientocapilar' => string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'tratamientocorporal' => string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'observaciones' => string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'enviar' => string 'Salvar' (length=6)
```

Comment: La función `public function ModificarCliente($id)` solo recibe como parámetro la variale `$id`, el resto que estás intentando pasar a la consulta `SQL`, `$datonombre`, `$datoapellido`, etc. no están dentro de la función, mientras no las pases a la clase o a la función, siempre te va a dar error. Deberías revisar la teoría sobre [Ámbito de las variables](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que las variables `$datonombre, $datonapellido`, etc. son variables que [existen fuera del ámbito](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) de la clase `ModificarCliente`

Soluciones:

- Incluir `datosclientes.php` dentro del método `ModificarCliente` (*poco prolijo*)

  ```
  public function ModificarCliente($id) {
      //
      require("datosclientes.php");

      // ... codigo actual ...
  ```

  Esto funcionará porque a la variable `$_POST` es `global`.
- Pasar al método `ModificarCliente` un arreglo con los datos del cliente (*más prolijo*)

  En *actualizacliente.php* vamos a pasar los datos del cliente en un arreglo.

  ```
  // La variable `$_POST` es un arreglo en la cual 
  // ya se encuentran todos los datos del cliente.
  $modificarcliente->ModificarCliente($_POST);
  ```

  En *modificarcliente.php* vamos modificar el método `ModificarCliente` para use el arreglo de datos.

  ```
  public function ModificarCliente($datos) {

     // try and catch para capturar errores
     try {

         // Sentencia SQL
         $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET
              nombre = '$datos[nombre]',
              apellidos = '$datos[apellidos]',
              alias = '$datos[alias]',
              telefono = '$datos[telefono]',
              movil = '$datos[movil]',
              email = '$datos[email]',
              direccion = '$datos[direccion]',
              poblacion = '$datos[poblacion]',
              provincia = '$datos[provincia]',
              codigopostal = '$datos[codigopostal]',
              tratamientocapilar = '$datos[tratamientocapilar]',
              tratamientocorporal = '$datos[tratamientocorporal]',
              observaciones = '$datos[observaciones]'
          WHERE idclientes = '$datos[idcliente]'";

         // ... codigo ...
  ```

**Nota**: Tu código es susceptible de inyección SQL, te aconsejo que [leas esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/16597) para que aprendas a prevenirlo.

Comment: Después de realizar los cambios con la segunda opción sigue sin funcionar, devuelve el mismo error, que no existen las variables de los campos.

Comment: @David he actualizado mi respuesta. Corregí el nombre de los campos en el arreglo `$datos`.

Comment: he añadido lo que me has dicho y modificado los datos y ahora no da error pero sólo me modifica los tres últimos campos. Debe ser una tontería, a mi vuelta lo miro detenidamente y miraré también lo de los marcadores de PDO para evitar inyección SQL.

Comment: Solucionado, gracias @Marcos Gallardo, ahora revisaré el tema de la inyección SQL.