# Error PDOStatement::bindParam()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Atendiendo al consejo que me disteis en la pregunta que realicé hace unos días ([Actualizar registros usando PDO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41154/actualizar-registros-usando-pdo)) estoy cambiando el código para evitar inyección SQL con PHP.

La cuestión es que al ejecutar la página de actualización me sale el siguiente error:

> PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 15 given 
>   Mensaje: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    // Incluimos la clase conexión para crear una que herede de Conexion
    require("conexion.php");

    /*
    * Clase modificar cliente que hereda las propiedades de la clase conexion
    */
   class ModificarCliente extends Conexion {

       // Constructor de la clase
       function __construct(){

           // Constructor de la super clase
           parent::__construct();

       }

    // Método para guardar las modificaciones del cliente
    public function ModificarCliente($datos) {

       // try and catch para capturar errores
       try {

           // Comprobamos que los campos no están vacíos
           if(empty($_POST)){

               echo "Los campos están vacíos, no se puede actualizar.";

           } else {

                // Si no están vacíos guardamos en la variable sql la sentencia de actualización
                $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET
                            nombre = ?,
                            apellidos = ?,
                            alias = ?,
                            telefono = ?,
                            movil = ?,
                            email = ?,
                            direccion = ?,
                            poblacion = ?,
                            provincia = ?,
                            codigopostal = ?,
                            tratamientocapilar = ?,
                            tratamientocorporal = ?,
                            observaciones = ?
                        WHERE idclientes = ?";

           }

            var_dump($datos);

            // Guardamos la variable SQL y preparamos la consulta con la conexion de la base de datos
            $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

            // Ligamos parámetros marcadores (?,?,?,... es decir, $datos[nombre], $datos[apellidos], ...)
            // Especificación de tipos de caracteres
            //i->la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
            //d->la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
            //s->la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
            //b->la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes

        $query->bindParam(1, $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(2, $datos['apellidos'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(3, $datos['alias'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(4, $datos['telefono'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(5, $datos['movil'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(6, $datos['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(7, $datos['direccion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(8, $datos['poblacion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(9, $datos['provincia'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(10, $datos['codigopostal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(11, $datos['tratamientocapilar'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(12, $datos['tratamientocorporal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(13, $datos['observaciones'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(14, $datos['idcliente'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        // Ejecutamos la consulta y la guardamos en un array
        $query->execute();

            // Guardamos el resultado en una variable
            $resultado = $query;

            // Cerramos la query
            $query->closeCursor();

            // Devolvemos los resultados a la función
            return $resultado;

            // Vaciamos el objeto
            $this->conexion_db = null;

         } catch (Exception $e) {

           echo "Error en la ejecución de la consulta<br>";
           echo "Mensaje: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>";
           echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine();

       }

    }
}
?>
```

Ejecuto `var_dump($datos)` y `var_dump($resultado)` para comprobar que si se están tomando los datos correctamente y esto es lo que muestra:

```
array (size=16)
  'idcliente' => string '10' (length=2)
  'nombre' => string 'Alicia' (length=6)
  'apellidos' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'alias' => string 'Alicia' (length=6)
  'telefono' => string '222' (length=3)
  'movil' => string '3333' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'a@a.com' (length=7)
  'direccion' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'poblacion' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'provincia' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'codigopostal' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tratamientocapilar' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tratamientocorporal' => string '555' (length=3)
  'observaciones' => string '444' (length=3)
  'enviar' => string 'Salvar' (length=6)
  'idclientes' => null

object(PDOStatement)[3]
  public 'queryString' => string 'UPDATE clientes SET

                            nombre = ?,

                            apellidos = ?,

                            alias = ?,

                            telefono = ?,

                            movil = ?,

                            email = ?,

                            direccion = ?,

                            poblacion = ?,

                            provincia = ?,

                            codigopostal = ?,

                            tratamientocapilar = ?,

           '... (length=646)
```

**Editado tras incluir de forma correcta el método bindParam**

He corregido el código para incluir de forma correcta bindParam para PDO, y no muestra ningún error, pero no actualiza los datos en la base de datos y no sé donde puede estar el fallo.

Con los datos de var_dump que podéis ver veo que el dato que uso para ir al registro `idclientes` está como `NULL`. El dato en la base de datos es de tipo entero y he probado a poner el texto como entero pero cuando hago un `gettype` me dice que es tipo `string`.

¿Puede venir el fallo de ahí?

**Editado tras solucionarlo**

Ya he dado con el problema, no estaba mirando correctamente al input `idcliente`, lo tenía en plural en el marcador en la posición 14 del `bindParam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) no puede recibir `sss...` como parámetros.

Esta sintaxis se usa en las preparaciones de [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php).

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar tu `$query->bindParam( ... )` a:

```
$query->bindParam(1, $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(2, $datos['apellidos'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(3, $datos['alias'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(4, $datos['telefono'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(5, $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(6, $datos['movil'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(7, $datos['direccion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(8, $datos['poblacion'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(9, $datos['provincia'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(10, $datos['codigopostal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(11, $datos['tratamientocapilar'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(12, $datos['tratamientocorporal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(13, $datos['observaciones'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(14, $datos['idclientes'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: He modificado el código tal y como me has comentado pero ahora no devuelve ningún error y en teoría debería actualizar los datos pero no lo hace. He editado la pregunta con los últimos cambios.

Comment: @David  - Prueba cambiar al idcliente de PDO::PARAM_STR a PDO::PARAM_INT

Comment: Acabo de dar, creo, con el problema. También he cambiado a entero esa posición @aldanux. Y ha modificado bien.

Answer (score 1):

El error te está indicando lo que es incorrecto:

> PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 15 given

Le estás pasando 15 parámetros cuando le deberías de pasar únicamente 5.

Desde la **[documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**, estos son los parámetros que deberías de pasarle:

- **parameter**

  El identificador del parámetro. Para sentencias preparadas que usen parámetros de sustición con nombre, esto será un nombre de parámetro con la forma :nombre. Para sentencias preparadas que usen parámetros de sustición de signos de interrogación, esto será la posición índice-1 del parámetro.
- **variable**

  Nombre de la variable de PHP a vincular al parámetro de la sentencia SQL.
- **data_type**

  El tipo de datos explícito para el parámetro, usando las constantes PDO::PARAM_*. Para devolver un parámetro INOUT desde un procedimiento almacenado, se ha de usar el operador OR a nivel de bits para establecer los bits de PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT para el parámetro data_type.
- **length**

  La longitud del tipo de datos. Para indicar que el parámetro es un parámetro OUT de un procedimiento almacenado, se debe establecer explícitamente la longitud.
- **driver_options**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la sintaxis `:variable` y a [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) pasarle un arreglo asociativo, por ejemplo:

```
$gsent = $gbd->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$gsent->execute(array(':calories' => $calorías, ':colour' => $color));
```

Aplicado a tú código:

```
$sql = "UPDATE clientes SET
          nombre = :nombre,
          apellidos = :apellidos,
          alias = :alias,
          telefono = :telefono,
          movil = :movil,
          email = :email,
          direccion = :direccion,
          poblacion = :poblacion,
          provincia = :provincia,
          codigopostal = :codigopostal,
          tratamientocapilar = :tratamientocapilar,
          tratamientocorporal = :tratamientocorporal,
          observaciones = :observaciones
          WHERE idclientes = :idcliente";

 // ...codigo...

 $query = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

 // Eliminamos el valor que esta de mas
 unset($datos['enviar']);

 // Pasamos el arreglo con exactamente los datos a mapearse
 $query->execute($datos);
```